# How can we retrieve both email addresses of the users accounts using query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, database-administration

I have tableA and tableB where I am running below query to get url having count greater than 1

```
select  
      group_concat(institution_user_id),
      url 
   from 
      tableA as s 
         join tableB as i 
            on s.jove_institution_id = i.institutionid  
   group by 
      url 
   having 
      count(*) > 1;
```

here I am getting multiple userids having url greater than 1.However I need email address of those users which is in tableC and which is having relation with tableA **institution_user_id** column with tableC **userid** column.Is it possible to create single query using tablec to get email address of the userids.

I tried below query but it is not providing expected result.

```
select (select email from tablecwhere userid in (group_concat(institution_user_id))), count(*) as c from tableA as s join tableB as i on i.institutionid = s.jove_institution_id group by shibboleth_metadata_url having c > 1;
```

Here I am getting list of email ids.But I need email id with user. For example ,If url [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) have 2 userids then I need query where I need email address of both userids of that url which is present in tablec

```
CREATE TABLE tableA(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  url varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  jove_institution_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  institution_user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
CREATE TABLE tableB (
  InstitutionID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  Approved tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  DateAdded datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  IsAcademic tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (InstitutionID)
);
CREATE TABLE tableC(
  EmailID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserID int(11) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(190) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  Verified tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  OptIn tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastverified datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EmailID)
);
```

Desired output

| userid | email | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | abc@gmail.com | xyz.com |
| 222 | def@gmail.com | xyz.com |

**sample data**

```
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (1,'xyz.com',23,111);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (2,'xyz.com',23,222);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (3,'pqr.com',24,111);

INSERT INTO tableB VALUES (23,'Baylor Health Sciences Library',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO tableB VALUES (24,'Macquarie University',1,NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO tableC VALUES (1234,111,'abc@gmail.com',1,NULL,'2018-03-14 13:21:04');
INSERT INTO tableC VALUES (4235,222,'def@gmail.com',1,NULL,'2018-03-14 13:22:11');
INSERT INTO tableC VALUES (4567,333,'stu@gmail.com',1,NULL,'2018-03-14 13:30:23');
```

Here url value **xyz.com** has 2 userid and with respect to userid we need to get email id from **tableC**.you can ignore **tableB** as it is using only for comparision.

**institution_user_id**  from tableA relation with **userid** from tableC.
**InstitutionID** from tableB relation with **jove_institution_id** from tableA.

Comment: question updated @Akina

Comment: question updated @Akina

Comment: sorry, question updated @Akina

Comment: No, I will not close, It will be help full for other as well. @DRapp

Comment: let me try,thank you so much for all the help @Akina

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O.  It took a while for you to get all the pieces intended to solve your issue and some people are just too short and want an easy answer to reply.  First, it is best to provide what you can of actual tables / columns, so if it does not have anything "confidential", dont change it.  Sample data can always mask that.

Now, to your query, first, start with all the relationships between the respective tables.  To keep that simple, you can use alias names vs longerTableNames.  Also, always try to use the table.column (or alias.column) to prevent ambiguity where columns are coming from.

So I would first start with the basic premise of getting TO all the pieces.  I dont even think you need TableB.

```
select
      u.url,
      u.email
   from
      TableC  u
         JOIN TableA i
            on u.userID = i.institution_user_id
   order by
      u.url,
      u.email
```

Starting with this basic query, all I care about is getting the USER (alias u) joined to the institution (alias i).  At this point, I don't care if one or more records.  At least now I have data.

Now, you only care about those that have a given url with more than one entry.  So now, I can apply a group by the URL and group concatinate the email and apply the count.

```
select
      u.url,
      group_concat( u.email ) allUserEMails
   from
      TableC  u
         JOIN TableA i
            on u.userID = i.institution_user_id
            -- just add the additional join from one to the next
            JOIN TableB ji
               on i.jove_institution_id = b.institutionID
   group by
      u.url
   having
      count(*) > 1
```

Is this what you are looking for?

if you also wanted all the IDs, you could also add

```
group_concat( u.userID) allUserIDs
```

See revised query, but if you are not doing anything with tableB otherwise, dont know why you need it.  If just to get some other name from that table, fine

Comment: this works but I need to compare InstitutionID from tableB relation with jove_institution_id from tableA.How can use this in query?

Comment: because I need to compare InstitutionID  and InstitutionID ,so I mentioned tableB @DRapp

Comment: @Kulal, revised my answer

Comment: @Kulal, also, as a newbie, here on S/O, if you find this or other answers positive / helpful, it is good to click the up arrow (down if a bad answer).  If you ask a question and get an answer that SOLVES your question, click the checkmark.  This way others having same problem know what DID work for you so questions dont have to be re-asked.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT tableC.UserID, 
                     tableC.email, 
                     tableA.url, 
                     COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tableA.url) cnt
              FROM tableA 
              JOIN tableB ON tableA.jove_institution_id = tableB.InstitutionID
              JOIN tableC ON tableA.institution_user_id = tableC.UserID )
SELECT UserId, email, url
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

If your version is 5.x then use

```sql
SELECT tableC.UserID, 
       tableC.email, 
       tableA.url
FROM ( SELECT url
       FROM tableA
       GROUP BY url
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) duplicated 
JOIN tableA ON tableA.url = duplicated.url
JOIN tableB ON tableA.jove_institution_id = tableB.InstitutionID
JOIN tableC ON tableA.institution_user_id = tableC.UserID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c2356b72df960978907d0f802fa8817e